# Is there a possibility to run the swf file to android 2.3?

Tags: android, flash

I'm currently developing an android apps and I want to attach a .swf file to it for some purpose(like play it in a webview).

Is there a way to do it ?
How should I start?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post relevant code? What do you want to attach the swf file to?

Comment: Do you want to play it in android webview ?

Comment: yes i want to play it in a webview. .

Comment: I've successfully done that using a WebView and PhoneGap, but that was back in 2010. The most important thing is to enable plugins for the WebView. You should be aware of the fact that the Flash Player is not available in Android versions beyond 4.0 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.flashplayer&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of adding resources to APKs:

Place it in `/res/raw` of your project or in the `assets` folder.

Guides for:

- [res/raw](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)
- [assets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html)

Comment: could the swf file runs on emulator? can i have a sample code sir? tnx